# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id`

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my code but I am getting an error at where clause

```
<?php

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$response = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.pizzahut.com.pk/deals.html");
//echo $dom->saveHTML();
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');


for($i = 30; $i < 35; $i++ ){
    $deal = $table->item($i)->nodeValue;
   echo $deal;
}
$id = 1813660169;
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cafes(deal)
        VALUES('$deal') WHERE `id` = " .$id) or die(mysql_error());


echo mysql_num_rows($result); 

if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Place successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = " ID already inserted";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }


?>
```

Error is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` = 1813660169' at line 2"

Help needed

Comment: you want to update column? then use update table set ... insert enter new row in and dont use where in syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should surround your variable with quotes `''`, simply change to

```
WHERE `id` = '" .$id."'")
```

As suggested you can't use `WHERE` in `INSERT` queries but you should use an `UPDATE` query so you syntax should look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE cafes set deal = '$deal' WHERE `id` = '" .$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I would like you to remember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: you can't have a `WHERE` clause in a basic `INSERT` statement. lastly, in an integer data type, a single quote around the value is unnecessary.

Comment: @jw correct, i didn't notice it was insert query

Answer (score 6):

You **cannot** have a `WHERE` clause in a basic `INSERT` syntax. What you really want, *i think*, is an `UPDATE` statement,

```
UPDATE cafes SET deal = '$deal' WHERE id = $id
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Insert statements do not specify a where clause, the row does not exist yet so there would be nothing to match against.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cafes(deal)
        VALUES('$deal')) or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is the basic syntax of an insert statement from the MySql website:

> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
>       [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
>       {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
>       [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>         col_name=expr
>           [, col_name=expr] ... ]

Notice the schematics do not contain a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use where clause in insert statement. Looks like you are looking for an UPDATE query try this

```
"UPDATE `cafes` SET deal =$deal where id =$id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use WHERE with an INSERT, although you can use a SELECT with INSERT, and the SELECT can have a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to add WHERE to insert? It is just the insertion of record to the table.